# QAbstractItemView - fetchMoreTimer

Tags: qt, dynamic-loading, qabstractitemview

I created dynamic loading model that supplies data to a modified qTreeView. Everything seemed to work fine. Until I realized that sometimes the GUI "waits" for something. 
It showed up that fetchMore of my model is called every now and then. I found out that there is "fetchMoreTimer" running in the QAbstractItemView (base class of most views)

1. rowInserted AND/OR updateGeometires gets called and starts the timer.
2. when the timer ticks it triggers timerEvent
3. timerEvent results in doItemsLayout()
4. doItemsLayout() ask canFetchMore (it sure can! I am dynamically loading millions of rows) and so the model fetches more.

And some time later the timer ticks again... resulting in virtually endless repaint of treeView (in main thread as all GUI opperations). This prevents for example load/save that is memory expensive. (saving loading data associated with millions of rows of data.)

Can someone suggest how to disable the fetchMoreTimer (of course in QAbstractItemViewPrivate :/)
I tried subclassing the timerEvent. But unfortunately about 6 different timers triggers the event and I don't know how to find out which I can ignore.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why you get this, but I think you should not. The fetchMoreTimer has an interval of 0, so it should not run just "sometimes". Also look into the [Fetch More Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html), if you add some outputs or breakpoints you can see that it clearly does not do that.

Comment: Exactly. The interval is 0 so the timer triggers as it is processed by the queue.
My fetchMore is based on the example you quoted. 
I do not understand why the fetchMoreTimer is started after rowInserted.
Because... even according to the example.
1. fetchMore calls endInsertRows and emits NumberPopulated.
2. I guess this leads to view function rowInserted.
3. rowInserted starts timer... which leads to repetitive fetchMore. Which again calls endInsertRows. (I just confirmed. It is endInsertRows that connects to views "rowsInserted" that starts the timer again

Comment: Sounds like you are scrolling the view to the end somewhere. This would need to fetch more items in each turn, then.